# Problems with install (live cd and alt ver. install)

Tags: 12.10, 9.10

I get into the live cd and get about halfway through installation (downloading packages) and keep receiving the message installation failed. When I use the alt version I get all the way to the point where its the select and install step, it gets about 15 percent of the way through and fails. when I select install grub bootloader this fails as well. The type of computer I am installing it on is a Dell Dimension XPS. I have downloaded and burned multiple copies of the Ubuntu and Lubuntu OS and ran several different disk checks as well as md5 checksums to insure the copies i am downloading and burning are complete. Now for my question, I am stumped on how to solve this any ideas/solutions?

Also the video card I have in the system is this right here (http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814161337 I have no clue as to whether this might help or not)

I have tried version 9.10, 12.10 of Ubuntu and 12.10 of Lubuntu to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to try the current LTS (Long Term Support) version of ubuntu (12.04(.1)) as it has fewer support issues and tends to be generally more stable.

If it fails on this you could try X/K/Lubuntu 12.04 although likelihood is these also wont work. Though there isn't a great deal of information to go by if it fails on "downloading packages" that may be network related, try unchecking the box which says "Download updates" on the first few pages of the installer.

You may get more out of this question by providing more info, such as all the information the installer gives you.

Comment: I'll check it out and see if that works, Thanks!

Comment: Alrighty I have figured out the problem completely! I did some searching on the internet for the error code I was receiving (errno 5 Input/Output error [copying issues i.e. hard drive/disc drive bad]) turns out neither of those were the issue. It was a memory leak (I'm assuming a bad one at that :P ) that was preventing the installation from continuing as soon as the files would start copying (loading up into memory?) so when it would (and I'm making relatively unknowledgeable guesses on this) the files could not be copied because they were fragmented(?) I guess would be the right word(?).

Comment: Sorry if this comes across as rude but.. Why didn't you put the error code(s) in the main question? Errors are crucial information.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't think about it at the time.

Comment: No problem. Sorry rereading that it appeared a bit aggressive, just take it as a hint for next time ;p

Comment: No problems, man! I didn't know a memory leak could cause that much trouble during an installation. It was very weird considering I've never had that problem before.